# PHP creating 2 rows and not checking input

Tags: php, mysql, validation, mysqli

What I'm trying to do is make a username (just username) get sent to a MySQL database, if it isn't already there.

Basically, I'm getting the input, checking it against all other rows in my `username` column, and, if the input is not the same as any of them, then add the input to the database. Here is my code:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



if( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) ) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO users (username)
    VALUES('$_POST[username]')";


    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["username"] == $_POST[username]) {
            die("Username is already in use!");
        }
    }
}


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    die("Error, please consult an admin: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error);
    }
$conn->close();
```

No error is reported, but it simply creates the data twice, and doesn't check the input. I can't see how. This is how I've tried. It looks logical that is should work, but it's not. Why?

I'm using MySqli Object-Orientated

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the $conn->query($sql) twice. The first one is in `$result = $conn->query($sql);` and the second `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)`. That is why you get 2 entries in the for one request.

First check for the user you are prepering to insert and if it returns 0 statements then go with the second `if` you have wrote.

Edit 2:

Try use PDO:

The code will look something like this:

```
if( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) ) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?");
    $stmt->execute( array( $_POST["username"] ) );
    $_results = $stmt->get_result();

    if( count( $_results ) > 0 ) {
        die("Error, please consult an admin!");
    } else {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES( ? )' );
        $stmt->bindParam( 1, $_POST['username'] );

        if( $stmt->execute() ) {
          echo 'Success';
        } else {
          echo 'Whoops, you have an error mate!';
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I changed connection to PDO, and copied the code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING) in addUser.php on line 26

Comment: Line 26 is `if(count( $_results ) > 0) {`

Comment: Try now with. Changed some things.

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ';' in addUser.php on line 20` what!? Line 20 is that `if(isset)` line!

Comment: Pasted the code from my IDE and runned a quick test. Pasted the code, I don`t know what to say :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



if( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) ) {
    $sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO users (username)
    VALUES('$_POST[username]')";


    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["username"] == $_POST[username]) {
            die("Username is already in use!");
        }
    }
    echo "New record created successfully";
}else {
    die("Error, please consult an admin: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error);
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: And it looks like you have to run another query to check if there is the same username already on use.
Now that i have updated the answer.

Comment: I would give you -1 because you didnt sanitize the data. MySql injection possibility there my friend.

Comment: Please if you wish. I appreciate if you edit this query (or your answer) by the proper query avoiding all possible attacks.

Comment: Added. Using PDO with prepare method will avoid the injection :)

Comment: What does `INSERT IGNORE` mean?

Comment: @Nebunel: That is out of requirement. If one ask for the way to 'south', do you say: "There is still raining in south, you better go north!"

Is this the best way to answer? Anyhow..I appreciate your deep care about injection.

playyip: Specify IGNORE to ignore rows that would cause duplicate-key violations. If you concentrate- I suggest to take a look at 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' also. For more about this go: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html